# Return TRUE from a views_php filter is not working as expected

Tags: php, drupal, view

I have written a Global PHP filter, in a View, and I am expecting the returned value to be TRUE when a condition is met and when `TRUE` it should eliminate that row from my result set. The view displays its results in a table.

The filter code I have is as follows

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
$bid = db_query("SELECT entity_id FROM {field_data_field_bid_request_reference} WHERE field_bid_request_reference_line_item_id = '$row->line_item_id'");
foreach($bid as $value) {
    $node_uid = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {node} WHERE nid = '$value->entity_id'")->fetchField();
    if( $node_uid != $uid) {
       return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I am getting the results I expect as far as the if statement. The `$node_uid` is returning exactly want I want, the `uid` for whoever created the node with the `nid` = to the `entity_id` obtained from the `db_query`.

In my testing I have 12 rows, each with a `line_item_id`. There are 6 possible results for `$node_uid` and I am seeing them if I use a `drupal_set_message` to look at the 4 `node_id` inside the foreach. In my test case I have a uid of 5 and this should match 3 times. I should only see 3 rows in my final results.

The problem is that the 9 rows that should be eliminated because they match the if statement and should return `TRUE` are actually the rows displayed and the 3 that should fail the if statement test and should be displayed are the ones being removed from the output. This is almost as if the return value is reversed.

What ever I do it is as if the return value is incorrect when the if statement passes.

I would have expected the cases where the `node_id` to not equal the `uid` to return `TRUE` and these lines to not appear in my table.

Can anyone offer any suggestions about what could be going wrong and also about how to debug this filter?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do - the "return TRUE" stops others from being processed so you never return the node_uid at all. BUT - reason for comment - is that you can do the above with one SQL statement, and probably should. BUT you probably can do it the level higher to return the 9 / 3 nodes in one go. So can you post the calling code, i.e. what builds your array, as it might be better to handle there. I'll also get more of an idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: As Robbie stated, it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do here, posting the calling code as well as a few example rows from the tables being queried should help.

Answer (score 1):

When the filter displays TRUE, it filters out, AFAIK. So, you should probably have

```
if ($node_uid == $uid) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Need two equals signs instead of one... `if ($node_uid == $uid) {`

Comment: I hate when I miss that stuff... Happens more often than I care to think about, too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use a `foreach` statement inside a `views_php` filter, only because the result of the filter is supposed to apply to one row and one row only. Kind of like "all or nothing".

I'd recommend editing the view and adding the the field **Content: Author uid** to the view, then adjusting your `views_php` filter like so:

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
$node_uid = $row->uid;
if ($node_uid != $uid) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Note: the variable `$row->uid` will not be available until *after* you add the **Content: Author uid** field to the view itself. And, you can optionally hide the value of the author uid from the view so no one sees it:

[image: Adding the author uid to each row and then hiding it from the view.]

Hope that helps...